# Greek cross fractal

Tags: recursive-algorithms, fractals

I need some code to generate a Greek cross fractal. Example:

[image: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Greek_cross_3D_1_through_4.png]

It must be made of increasingly smaller panels, but the panels may not overlap with previous panels.

Does anyone know where I might find code like this? Thanks!

Comment: Acceptable programming languages include...?

Comment: JavaScript, pseudocode. Something loosely typed preferably.

Comment: This is a math site. If you need some code, why not post to a coding site?